# GridView Column sort in descending

Tags: c#, asp.net

welcome all
I have a simple code that displays the values in a GridView
When sorting, the result is ascending
I want the opposite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytBha.jpg)

I used this code
But I want to reverse the order

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "MYPoints";
GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "MYPoints DESC";
```